# Can you getElementsByName if you only have partial name on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a repeating table where the name of the elements would be (e.g. 'tdName_1' 'tdName_2'), and I was wondering if it would be possible to getElementsByName('tdName_').

PS: I can not use Jquery.

Thanks In advance.

Cesar.

Comment: Are the elements with names like 'tdName_1' <td>s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. I'm assuming for the rest of this answer that the elements you're interested in are `<td>`s. If so, then you should be aware that the `name` attribute is not valid for `<td>` elements.

You will have to create a list of matching elements manually. If you decide to use the `name` attribute anyway (instead of, say, adding a class in the `class` attribute), something like the following will work:

```
var table = document.getElementById("your_table_id");
var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
var matchingTds = [];

for (var i = 0, len = tds.length, td, tdName; i < len; ++i) {
    td = tds[i];
    tdName = td.getAttribute("name");
    if (tdName && tdName.indexOf("tdName_") == 0) {
        matchingTds.push(td);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim I did not know that name attribute are not valid for td tags. Vote for You.

Comment: The answer is a little old and still valid, but it could have a splash of functional programming added to it since most browsers now support `[].filter`.

`var table = document.getElementById("your_table_id");
var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
var matchingTds = tds.filter(function(td) {
    tdName = td.getAttribute("name");
    return (tdName && tdName.indexOf("tdName_") === 0);
});`

Comment: @nickytonline: It's true that most browsers support `filter` on arrays, but `getElementsByTagName()` does not return an array; it returns an `HTMLCollection`, which doesn't have a `filter` method. You could do something like `var matchingTds = [].filter.call(table.getElementsByTagName("td"), function(td) { ... })` instead.

Comment: @tim-down, correct, my bad. That's what happens when I comment without fully testing my suggestion ;) I saw the  `[]` in the Chrome dev tools, so just assumed array but as you mentioned, in fact it's a node collection ;)

Answer (score 6):

With vanilla javascript you can use the querySelectorAll method:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name^=tdName]')
```

This should work in all modern browsers, including IE9 or later (though I haven't tested it yet).

Answer (score 3):

Not easy or probably possible with `getElementsByClassName` but you can put JQuery at rescue:

```
$('td[name=tdName_1]') // matches exactly 'tdName_1'

$('td[name^=tdName]') // matches those that begin with 'tdName'
```

Comment: quote from the question: `PS: I can not use Jquery.`

Comment: @Andy: yeah i did not notice that, but he should use jquery someday or the other and there are questions for which jquery turns out be extremely handy.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, not. But you can use getElementsByTagName() and then filter by name:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function find(){
    var inputs = document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("input");
    var found = [];
    for(var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++){
        if(inputs[i].name.match(/^tdName_\d+$/)){
            found.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    alert(found.length + " elements found");

}
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" id="foo">
    <input type="text" name="tdName_1">
    <input type="text" name="tdName_2">
    <input type="text" name="tdName_3">
    <input type="text" name="not_me">
    <input type="text" name="tdName_4">
    <input type="text" name="neither_me">
    <input type="text" name="tdName_5">
    <input type="button" onclick="find()" value="Find">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `getElementsByName` requires a static string as an argument.

I don't know if you have any control over the elements, but you should probably give them the same name and use `getElementsByName`.

Another solution would be to loop through names and use `getElementByName('tdName_' + i)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to fetch all relevant elements - e.g. using [**`getElementsByTagName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) - and loop through them until you find one or more elements that fit your criteria.

Maybe you can work around using [**`getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and give every element you want to match a certain class? (Update, the native version is not availalable on SO, thanks Andy E. [**This**](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) is a very popular workaround implementation.)

You say you can't use JQuery and I'm sure you have a good reason for that, but stuff like this is what Frameworks are there for. Would Prototype or MooTools be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, `getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE :-( `getElementsByTagName` is probably the best option

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Down said, the `name` attribute is not valid for `<td>` elements.  It should still work if you decide to use it though.  One option is to use a while loop, like this:

```
function getAllNamedTDs ()
{
    var cTD, i=1, elArr = []; 

    // If an element with "tdName_"+i is not found, exit the loop
    while (cTD = document.getElementByName("tdName_"+(i++)))
        elArr.push(cTD);

    // return the array of elements or null if no elements were found.
    return elArr.length ? elArr : null;
}
```

Instead of using the `name` attribute, you should use the `id` attribute and then replace `getElementByName` with `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

put TWO (2) names on each element you want to find...  make the first class name the same on every element and the second class name 'tdName_1' or 'tdName_2' (or whatever).    Run document.getElementsByClassName on the class name common to all your elements... then loop through the array, do className.split(' ') to get an array where array[0] is the common name and array[1] is the differentiated name, and...   do what you need to ...